# Second quantization for atomic or molecular models

Tags: quantum-field-theory, atomic-physics, second-quantization, quantum-chemistry

I'm trying to learn QED in the context of quantum chemistry (ie to model relativistic effects for heavy atoms) and I'm struggling conceptually with second quantization: specifically, what is the motivation for "particles" in this context?

I understand that in a scattering model, particles - and hence Fock states - are a natural concept, because they're the observables (in free space, far from the interaction). But in the context of an atom or a molecule, I don't see how the concept of particles really arises given that as far as I'm aware we can't observe a bound electron? Surely here our observables are things like the energy of the entire bound Dirac field in which case the motivation behind second quantization seems obscure.

Am I just missing something fundamental here? Or is there an alternative way to think about QED in this context that doesn't rely on introducing the concept of "particles"?

Comment: Is the use of QED in this context just treating the position of the nuclei as fixed and the electromagnetic field due to the nuclei as an external field?

Comment: Yes, exactly - the Born-Oppenheimer model

Comment: You only need relativistic quantum chemistry for this. QED only comes in if you require radiation corrections for high accuracy.